# AWS EC2 instance automically creates new when stopped

Tags: .net, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am fairly new to using aws ec2 instances but this one has me perplexed.  Everytime I stop or terminate any of my test instances, they stop but then shortly after seem to spawn off a new instance of the same name and instance type.  I tried changing the Shutdown Behavior from Stop to Terminate, but that didn't fix the issue.  All I am trying to do is create a test environment for a .net app I inherited.  Has anyone seen this before?

Comment: Sounds like you have an autoscaling group.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is generally a symptom of auto-scaling. I think your EC2 instance is part of an auto-scaling group with a minimum size of 1 instance. So when it stops a new one is launched automatically.

Comment: Have a look at this: [Detach EC2 Instances From Your Auto Scaling Group](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AutoScaling/latest/DeveloperGuide/detach-instance-asg.html)

Answer (score 0):

Autoscaling group with min, max, desired = 1 does something like this. If you change min to 0, all your instances can be terminated without getting a new one.

You need to create a Launchconfig and an AutoScalingGroup with this LaunchConfig.
[AutoScaling getting started](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AutoScaling/latest/DeveloperGuide/GettingStartedTutorial.html)

You can use Elastic Beanstalk, it's really easy. (And saves you a lots of time on managing your system.)
[Elastic Beanstalk with .NET guide](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_NET.html)